# query not returning the right data

Tags: mysql

**Payment_Detail_Table**

```
payment_detail_id| payment_id | payment_status | total | user_id | company_id
10001            |          10|    1           | 100        1          103
10002            |          11|    2           | 200        1          103
10003            |          12|    2           | 300        2          104
10004            |          13|    1           | 400        2          104
10005            |          14|    0           | 500        1          105
10006            |          15|    2           | 600        1          103
```

**Payment_Table**

```
payment_id| payment_type| 
10        |          1  |    
11        |          1  |    
12        |          1  |    
13        |          1  |    
14        |          0  |    
15        |          0  |
```

How to get the `user_id`s that have `payment_type` of `1` and `payment_type` of `0` from `Payment_Table`?

The purpose is to find that they have made two kind of payments and for those who have paid two of them, they must have `payment_status` of `2` , but if
for example, if the `user_id` is `1` and `company_id` is `103`,  the output must be `100+200+600=900`.

This user with this `company_id` has the `payment_Type` `0` and `1` and for those two conditions `(payment_type=1 and payment_type=0)` have finished them successfully with `payment_Status` of `2` even though have a failed payment earlier

For example `payment_detail_id` is `1001` have `payment_status` of `1`.

Comment: Please use punctuation in your problem statement.  It is hard to follow.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Sorry for about that cuz I'm new to stackoverflow and i needed a quicker solution.

Comment: You can add here what your output looks like

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for ?

```
SELECT user_id, company_id
FROM (select payment_detail_table.user_id AS user_id,payment_detail_table.company_id AS company_id
from payment_detail_table
where (EXISTS(SELECT * FROM payment_table WHERE payment_table.payment_id=payment_detail_table.payment_id AND payment_table.payment_type=1)) AND payment_detail_table.payment_status = 2
group by concat(payment_detail_table.user_id,'-',payment_detail_table.company_id)) T1
INNER JOIN
(SELECT payment_detail_table.user_id AS user_id,payment_detail_table.company_id AS company_id
FROM (select payment_detail_table.user_id AS user_id,payment_detail_table.company_id AS company_id
from payment_detail_table
where (EXISTS(SELECT * FROM payment_table WHERE payment_table.payment_id=payment_detail_table.payment_id AND payment_table.payment_type=0)) AND payment_detail_table.payment_status = 2
group by concat(payment_detail_table.user_id,'-',payment_detail_table.company_id)) T2
USING (user_id, company_id)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
  DISTINCT user_id
FROM
  Payment_Detail_Table D
WHERE
  EXISTS(
    SELECT
      *
    FROM
      Payment_Table P1
    WHERE
      P1.payment_id = D.payment_id
    AND
      P1.payment_type = 1
  )
AND
  EXISTS(
    SELECT
      *
    FROM
      Payment_Table P2
    WHERE
      P2.payment_id = D.payment_id
    AND
      P2.payment_type = 0
   )
```

Comment: I don't understand the rest of the question (after "The purpose is to find...")

Comment: And why do you think that this is a valid answer if you only understand half of the question?

Comment: @NicoHaase It's the answer to the first part (which is actually the only question asked: "How to get the user_ids that have payment_type of 1 and payment_type of 0 from Payment_Table?")